# Rules for unquoted JavaScript Object Literal Keys?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, you can define an object like this:

```
var d = {1: 'test'};
```

and I can set a key with a negative number index like this:

```
d[-1] = 'test2';
```

but if I try to use a negative number in the literal initialization, I get an error:

```
var d = {1: 'test', -1: 'test2'};
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
```

Why is this? Why can't I use a literal negative number as a key to an object? Is there a workaround that allows me to initialize it as a literal. I know I could use strings instead, but I want to use integers.

Comment: use quotes around property name like '-1':'test2'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [***Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), my write-up on the subject:

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or [a valid identifier name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
>
> […]
>
> Bracket notation can safely be used for all property names.
>
> […]
>
> Dot notation can *only* be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.

`-1` is not a numeric literal, it’s a unary `-` operator followed by a numeric literal (`1`).

I also made a tool that will tell you if any given property name can be used without quotes and/or with dot notation. Try it at [mothereff.in/js-properties](http://mothereff.in/js-properties).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you meant "unary `-` operator."

Comment: Your tool claims that `-1` and `+1` can be used as unquoted property names, even though they don't actually work.

Comment: @StuartCook Thanks for the report! [Fixed](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/mothereff.in/commit/705c840bb4e96671b678037246b5704ac24045e9): http://mothereff.in/js-properties#-1 (You might need to refresh to update the appcache.)

Comment: @MathiasBynens, Are there any limits if the key is quoted?

Comment: @Pacerier As long as you use a valid string, there are no such limits at the language-level, no.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question.

The thing is, there's no difference between typing

```
var d = {24: 'foo'};
```

and

```
var d = {"24": 'foo'};
```

You can verify this by doing:

```
var d = {24:'foo', "24":'bar'};
```

Notice that it only has one "24" property (and fails in strict mode).

So while this doesn't explain why you can't do -1 without quotes, hopefully it does explain that "-1" is just as good.

Interestingly, unquoted fractional numbers seem to work fine.

Edit: Felix Kling explains why it doesn't work in a comment on another answer. `-1` isn't a numeric literal, it's an expression with a numeric literal and a unary `-` operator -- therefore it's not suitable as an object key.

Answer (score 3):

Its because `-1` isn't a valid variable identifier.

Comment: But I can still assign it by key later, so is this a limitation of the literal syntax that keys have to be valid variable names?

Comment: Correct. its just a representation of hte object.

Comment: @jterrace, @Daniel: Property names in object initializers can be string literals and numeric literals as well (not only identifier names). But apparently, `-1` is not a numeric literal: http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.3

Comment: @FelixKling aha, you're right, it's a numeric literal with a unary operator prepended, of course!

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
var d = { 1: 'test', '-1': 'test2'};
```

Identifiers, that are keywords or can not be a normal identifier for other reasons, can still be used if surrounded by quotes.

Comment: `1` cannot be used as identifier either... just saying ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why, but you have to quote the negative number in the object initializer:

```
var d = {1: 'test', '-1': 'test2'};
```

All object keys are treated as strings internally, so you can address this key using either:

```
d[-1] or d['-1']
```

Answer (score 1):

When the key contains certain characters, you have to put it in quotes like this:

```
var d = {"1": 'test', "-1": 'test2'};
```

Here's a pretty good reference on what characters are allowed without the quoting and it has a specific section about object property declaration too: http://asenbozhilov.com/articles/identifiers-en.html#identifier_start.