# v-bind:style syntax not working in inline styles

Tags: vue.js, inline-styles

I'm fairly knew to Vue and the whole `v-bind` thing is throwing me for a loop...

Basically, I'm trying to achieve this syntax, but with Vue's `v-bind`, since I can't use a variable in an inline CSS style:

```
<div class="card" style="background-color: {{school.color}}">
```

Here's my Vue syntax, which I've followed from their documentation, but it's still throwing an error and I can't figure out why? Obviously, it has to be something simple, I just don't fully understand the intricacies of Vue yet!

```
<div class="card" :style="{ background-color: school.color }">
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If I answered your question, then you can click the checkmark beside my answer to mark it as correct ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For [object syntax bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) you are binding an *object*. Thus, the keys must be valid, and need to be quoted unless they are [valid unquoted keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367572/rules-for-unquoted-javascript-object-literal-keys). Dashes `-` are not allowed in unquoted keys, so it fails to compile.

Either of these options will work:

```
<div class="card" :style="{ 'background-color': school.color }">
```

or

```
<div class="card" :style="{ backgroundColor: school.color }">
```

Comment: Ha! That was simple. I've been going crazy trying to figure this out and it's just a simple quotation mark. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! My original explanation wasn't quite right... I've edited it to better explain why the quotes are necessary.

Comment: Excellent! Worked for me!