# Access Javascript Object Key with special symbol

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var obj = {
a?: "abc"
}
```

Want to access Key Which is Not in a valid format.

Giving me Error.

I'm accessing it like this obj.a.

and this is throwing an error.

```js
const obj = { a?: 'aaa' }
console.log(obj.a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work (not tested)

```
obj['a?'];
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### Valid property names
>
> Looking at the ECMAScript spec grammar, we can see that a property
> name can be either an identifier name (i.e. identifiers + reserved
> words), a string literal, or a numeric literal.
>
> Identifier names are a superset of identifiers; any valid identifier
> and any reserved word is a valid identifier name.
>
> [...]
>
> ### When can the quotes be omitted?
>
> Unless an object key is a numeric literal or a valid identifier name,
> you need to quote it to avoid a syntax error from being thrown. In
> other words, quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a
> numeric literal or a valid identifier name. Of course, if the property
> name is a string literal, it’s already quoted by definition

source: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties

To solve your specific issue you can use `quotes`:

```
var obj = {
'a?': "abc"
}

obj['aj']
```

Full answer can be found at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571440/1211174

Comment: First, *You can do* is not an explanation. Please explain why your answer solves anything. Second, since you know the issue, you are more likely to find a better duplicate. You should look for it rather than answering.

Comment: @Rajesh you are right, fixed

Answer (score -2):

The key should be a simple string in JavaScript, so if you change from a? to a, it should work.