# JavaScript - How do I dynamically assign a new key value pair to an object, using object-literal, and bracket notation, spread syntax in a one-liner?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, key

I want to dynamically specify negative values as seen in this exact question.

[Rules for unquoted JavaScript Object Literal Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367572/rules-for-unquoted-javascript-object-literal-keys)

I want to also accomplish this using some method of dynamic bracket notation, using a string equivalent of a negative remainder (modulus operation).

bucketObj[key] reports undefined, since I have not pre set a key to store a corresponding value.  How do I dynamically set a key of an object in either bracket notation, dot notation, or both?

```js
 function toDigitBuckets(array, radix) {
    let bucket = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...Array(radix).fill([])]));
    let bucketObj = Object.assign(bucket);
    array.forEach(val => { let key = String.toString(val % 10); bucketObj[key].push(val) });
    return bucket; 
  }
  
  let array = [-7, -49, 84, 39, -31, 95, 7, -8, -13, -32, 93, 40, -81, -30, -57, -57, 49, 66, -64, 42, 35, 29, -57, 41, 93, 34, -45, -15, 51, 16, 97, -88, 52, -69, 56, -16, -91, 51, 10, -21, 80, 78, -5, 18, -20, -98, 72, -94, 11, -83, -31, 13, -21, 39, -47, 8, -98, 95, 52, -18, 77, -11, -38, -46, -98, 48, -45, -4, 76, -32, -81, 67, -82, 9, -60, -20, 0, 33, -12, 77, 65, 45, -22, 99, -47, -83, -81, 10, -99, 16, 23, 5, -57, 89, -62, 9, -16, 79, 5, -2];
  
  let radix = 10;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(toDigitBuckets(array, radix)));
```

Comment: I hope I have not inadvertently hinted an answer to my question, but I suspect my brain was giving me clues that might help.   An answer would be helpful still for vote consideration.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Something like `array.forEach(val => { key = String.toString(val % 10); {...<spread existing pairs>,[key]:val }});`

Comment: Please suggest if my <spread existing pairs> is just the object label, if so that is really cool

Comment: i have no idea. please add the result in literal notation.

Comment: This is the most concise I got, no syntax underlines show up :  `array.forEach(val => { return {...bucket, [key]:val}});`  and the Object Literal is `{...bucket, [key]:val}`  where bucket is the object to have a new key added dynamically

Comment: The answer above does not accomplish the desired result because, from what I know forEach does not return a value.   My answer is close, but I need to find an alternate close version of the way I chose.

Comment: I have provided a check mark to accept,  I was a little out of sync yesterday, thanks for the reminder.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object as the accumulator. Each time a new key is encountered, first set that property value to be an empty array.

```js
function toDigitBuckets(array, radix) {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => 
    ((acc[curr % radix] ??= []).push(curr), acc), {});
}
let array = [-7, -49, 84, 39, -31, 95, 7, -8, -13, -32, 93, 40, -81, -30, -57, -57, 49, 66, -64, 42, 35, 29, -57, 41, 93, 34, -45, -15, 51, 16, 97, -88, 52, -69, 56, -16, -91, 51, 10, -21, 80, 78, -5, 18, -20, -98, 72, -94, 11, -83, -31, 13, -21, 39, -47, 8, -98, 95, 52, -18, 77, -11, -38, -46, -98, 48, -45, -4, 76, -32, -81, 67, -82, 9, -60, -20, 0, 33, -12, 77, 65, 45, -22, 99, -47, -83, -81, 10, -99, 16, 23, 5, -57, 89, -62, 9, -16, 79, 5, -2];
let radix = 10;
console.log(toDigitBuckets(array, radix));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```